# method personal_signTransaction not supported

Tags: ether

Good Time

I'm trying to test a smart contract in local ethereum wallet with connecting to the ganache-cli but when I try to create a wallet contract it gives me an error:

> method personal_signTransaction not supported

I tried both 11.1 and 11.0 version of wallet

help me please

Answer (score 0):

Ganache does not support personal_signTransaction. The alternative is to unlock the personal account then sign the transaction:

```
web3.personal.unlockAccount(addr, pass);
const toAddress = "0x....; //address of the recipient
const amountToSend = web3.toWei(2, "ether"); //convert to wei value
var send = web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:addr,to:toAddress, value:amountToSend});
```

Or sign the Tx with the private Key and send the raw Tx.

You can find a more detailed explanation on [this response](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42929/send-payment-from-wallet-using-web3#answer-42931)