# Website that sends eth to a specified adress

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I'm trying to make a button on my website which allows people to send Ethereum to a specified address. Once clicked, it should for example pop up a MetaMask window where the user can enter the amount of Eth (and optionally fees) and only needs to click send to make the transaction.
I have no clue how this is done, since i am nota programmer. and i cant seem to find anything on the internet aswell. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Research transactions with Web3.

Basically you will need to integrate web3 into your website. The texts below can help you:

[Send payment from wallet using web3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42929/send-payment-from-wallet-using-web3)

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html

https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-send-ethereum-transactions-using-web3-d05e0c95f820

There is no ready-made answer on how to do this since you want to build this system, which is also not that complex from a development standpoint. Also search on github if you find any such system.

Check this option as the best answer and give a positive vote if it helps you on your way to becoming a blockchain dev :)